# how to create right and left Title for bootstrap Panels

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I whant to create panel with two title
[image]

when I use this code my title are hide !

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ChatDialog">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title text-left pull-left"><%#Eval("ErrorTag")%></h3>
                        <h3 class="panel-title text-right pull-right"><%#Eval("Date")%></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <%#Eval("ErrorText")%>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </div>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

like bellow :
[image]

how I can solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of floats by adding `clearfix` for `<div class="panel-heading">` like this `<div class="panel-heading clearfix">` it will fix the issue